# When to use Global Variables (Reducing Global Variables vs DRY)

Tags: c#, global-variables

Based on the school of thought that Global Variables should be reduced wherever possible, I am trying to find the sweet science on if/when I should use given DRY and have a global variable or when I should repeat variables

Let's say you have a class as such:

```
    // Assuming Transient DI if interfaces used and (not Scoped or Singleton)
    public class MyClass
    {
        public StringBuilder Sb => new StringBuilder();

        public MyClass() 
        {
            // potential SB instantiation here
        }

        public void MyNeededSbMethodOne()
        {
            Sb.Append("Needed Sb One");
            // ... do something different with Sb
        }

        public void MyNeededSbMethodTwo()
        {
            Sb.Append("Needed Sb Two");
            // ... do something different with Sb
        }

        public void MyNeededSbMethodThree()
        {
            Sb.Append("Needed Sb Three");
            // ... do something different with Sb
        }
    }
```

For something like this, I am torn between inlining in each method with instantiating in each method to avoid global variables vs. reducing code (DRY) to have a clear understanding of the Goldilock zone of when it is acceptable to use. Is this an acceptable use case for a global variable?

Comment: Is the `do something different with Sb` alwas different in every class? Because if not... I would consider making a Stringbuilder extension out of the methods.

Comment: Great point! (will come back to +1 it when I have enough points) ... For if it was the same it allows the method to be `Sb.PerformActionMethod(inputVariable);` and even further conforms to DRY (reducing code from that perspective). Making that argument, the Global Variable would be a good use case? Leaving only, if it was for a different purpose since the variable is for different purposes, should the Sb still be used?

Comment: Well it depends what you want to do with the SB... What should happen to it's values? In my opinion there are just a very small amount of cases that really has a good reason of being a global variable e.g. global application settings.

Comment: You've misconstrued DRY. Don't bother with it right now. Learn about variable scope and how to apply OOP principles. DO repeat yourself until you get those right.

Comment: Understood and will do. Thank you.

@LegacyCode Global application settings as an example make a lot of sense and help clarify a use case for a global variable perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends from context and how you will use your variable (@Legacy Code make good point with Extension Methods).

In your example you are using `StringBuilder` which complicates a few things because of its nature and when to use it. I assume that is just for example but it is good to show few things.

You are making new string builder for every call to `Sb` and for single thread application it would be waste of resources (of course in critical scenarios when performance is the key. Also `+` or `.Concat()` might be more efficient, depends on context), you could for every method reuse same string builder but you have to remember to clear buffer at the beginning or end of method and make it private! Global variables are variables accessible from almost every place in code and that is what makes them dangerous, if you expose global variable from class as public there is threat that some other class changes it state **and it is the main reason for avoiding global variables**. There is thing like encapsulation which helps to keep your code DRY and you should check it out because I don't see why this variable should be public and in further text i will assume that it is changed to private.

From the other hand in multi thread application reusing StringBuilder might cause overriding or lose of data for different threads so in that scenario you have to create new variable every time.

Going more deep into scenario. You want to use DI and expose instances in transient scope so in most cases it would be used only once and only one method call will be performed so there is no much difference.

I will sign under what @madreflection said:

> Don't bother with it right now. Learn about variable scope and how to apply OOP principles. DO repeat yourself until you get those right.

Every thing depends on context and if you want to reuse resources or speed up performance you sometimes trade that for code quality. You have to analyze your context and things around it.

Global variables should be used in most cases as read only to be thread save and avoid uncontrolled state changes. Or as @Legacy Code said for global settings which will apply to application in controlled way that they were designed to do so.